# JavaScript or jQuery - Resizing tables according to div height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a HTML Table that I'm using as a calendar. Normally, this calendar is viewed at 690 pixels wide which makes each column 98 pixels wide (690 / 7 = 98). I want each date to be square, so they're also 98 pixels on the height.

I have a CSS class that is used on all of the dates. This has the height property set to 98 pixels. I also have a button at the bottom that lets the users view the calendar at full screen. So that means that the table width would be set to 100% (because of all of the different screen resolutions). But, again, I need all of the dates to be square. So I need some JavaScript or (preferably) jQuery to calculate what 14% of the screen resolution is (because there's 7 days and its across 100% of the screen. So now each column will be 14%).

I assume that the jQuery would be better for this because of changing the CSS height property to whatever is calculated, but JavaScript will work too.

I know nothing about jQuery and I don't know how to do this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery it's pretty simple. If you want to know the window with you can use

```
var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width()
```

End since all of your dates have a specific class (.dateElement for example) you can use jQuery to resize all of them using

```
jQuery('.dateElement').width(screenWidth * 14 / 100).height(screenWidth * 14 / 100);
```

You have to call this code when the function resize and jQuery has a very nice event for that:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){// Your code });
```

Hope this helps
Fabio

Comment: I guess I should have said that this will be on a separate page. For example. You will be on mysite.com/calendar.html when you see the standard calendar (690px wide). And then youll click Full Screen and it will take you to mysite.com/fs_calendar.html. This will be the calendar that is 100% wide. I need jQuery to calc the height of each day class.
I added the following code in the `<head>` section and it returns a syntax error.
`<script type="text/javascript">
var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery('.day').width(screenWidth 14 / 100).height(screenWidth * 14 / 100);
</script>`

Comment: Hi you have done it right, if you put the code inside the newly opened page should work. The Syntax error come from the fact that i've forgot the * symbol in my code before 14, my bad sorry. I've just edited my response

Answer (score 0):

You probably need window.innerWidth, and $(window).on('resize', fn) event to check when window size changes.

But better way is just add classes that set width to 14% of container